Troubleshooting wireless dongle
What I understand is that it's recognized as a networking device but I have no option to connect to a wireless network. Also I found that the driver for r8169 is supposed to come with the kernel.
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3151:4015 ROYUAN Akko Multi-modes Keyboard-B
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1462:7c95 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c547 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 007: ID a69c:8d80 aicsemi AIC Wlan
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 21b4:0082 AudioQuest DragonFly Red
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/aic8800

fatal: Zielpfad 'aic8800' existiert bereits und ist kein leeres Verzeichnis. 

cd aic8800

~/aic8800$ sudo cp -r src /usr/src/aic8800-1.0.6 

~/aic8800$ sudo dkms install aic8800/1.0.6 

Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/aic8800/1.0.6/source -> /usr/src/aic8800-1.0.6
    
Building module: Cleaning build area... arch='x86_64' kernelver='6.8.0-51-generic' ./driverctl make all...(bad exit status: 2) ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for aic8800: 1.0.6 not found Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-51-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/aic8800/1.0.6/build/make.log for more information.


Is it a USB dongle?

@RA Yes it is a USB dongle.

Run in terminal sudo /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -KQ -v a69c -p 5723 then run lsusb and edit the question to include the updated results

@Jeremy31 Done.

See https://kanyi.gm/how-to-install-and-enable-aic8800-chipset-wi-fi-driver-for-linux/

@Jeremy31 During install, I get an error (see above). Secure boot is enabled.

Disable Secure Boot, in terminal run sudo -i
echo 'ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="a69c", ATTR{idProduct}=="5723", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -KQ -v a69c -p 5721"' >/etc/udev/rules.d/50-custom.rules
exit
sudo dkms uninstall aic8800/1.0.5
sudo dkms remove aic8800/1.0.5 --all
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/aic8800
cd aic8800
sudo cp -r src /usr/src/aic8800-1.0.6
sudo dkms install aic8800/1.0.6
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/aic8800D80.git
cd aic8800D80
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/aic8800D80
sudo cp aic8800D80/* /lib/firmware/aic8800D80/

Reboot

Maybe I'm stupid but "exit" doesn't seem to work. See above.

@H3R3T1K fixed that

Sorry to bother. After the echo command the process doesn't terminate so when I enter the following commands, they have no effect (see greater-than signs above). I have to ctrl+c to be able to continue. Am I supposed to do that?

I edited the command before exit so it should work now

It does not, unfortunately.

echo 'ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="a69c", ATTR{idProduct}=="5723", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -KQ -v a69c -p 5721"' >/etc/udev/rules.d/50-custom.rules should work, had the wrong punctuation at the beginning
